# Защита от SQL инъекций

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Как переписать запрос, чтобы защититься от SQL инъекций?

```
function  getPass($current_pass)
{
    global $mysqli;
    if ($check = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = ?"))
    {
        $check->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['id']);
        $check->execute();
        $check->bind_result($current_pass);
        $check->fetch();
        $check->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: А где вы тут видите возможность SQL инъекции?

Comment: Я думал в запросе самом.. Или тут нету возможности для инъекции?

Comment: Ну если у вас в сессии кто-то сторонний может записывать данные, то да, SQL-инъекцию можно осуществить. Но если кто-то сторонний получил доступ к сессиям, то зачем ему SQL-инъекции, тут сразу доступ к админке организовать можно и делать, что пожелаешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вообще надо читать документацию:

> Экранирование и SQL инъекции
>
> **Значения привязанных к запросу переменных сервер экранирует автоматически**. Серверу необходима подсказка в виде указания типов привязываемых переменных, чтобы правильно преобразовать их значения. Дополнительную информацию см. в описании функции mysqli_stmt_bind_param(). Привязанные переменные отправляются на сервер отдельно от запроса и таким образом не могут влиять на него. Сервер использует эти значения непосредственно в момент выполнения, уже после того, как был обработан шаблон выражения. **Привязанные параметры не нуждаются в экранировании**, так как они никогда не подставляются непосредственно в строку запроса. Необходимо отправлять тип привязанной переменной на сервер, чтобы определить соответствующее преобразование. Смотрите функцию mysqli_stmt_bind_param() для получения большей информации.

http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 4):

Предполагается, что при использовании подобной записи вы полностью защищены от инъекций. На самом деле вы полагаетесь на утверждение, что инъекция полностью исключена до обнаружения какого нибудь бага. Возможно я выполняю множество лишних действий, но всегда стараюсь перестраховаться.

Все входные параметры я всегда проверяю на то, что они соответствуют ожидаемому типу. Например использую регулярные выражения или явные приведения типов. В любом случае если вы обнаружите какую либо ошибку в ожидаемом поведении данных это будет повод к разбору ситуации и выяснении возможных причин подобного явления.

```
if(is_numeric($_SESSION["id"])) {
...
}
```

или

```
$id=(int)$_SESSION["id"];
```

Хотя последний вариант возможно вызовет споры, т.к. поведение якобы не определено. В любом случае подобная конструкция должна возвращать целочисленный тип или вызывать исключение. Поведение позволяющее вернуть оригинальную переменную разработчик в здравом умен не должны оставлять.

Comment: Судя по этой строке `$check->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['id']);` у автора вопроса в `$_SESSION['id']` строка, а не число.

Comment: Visman, Это не имеет значения. Я просто привел пример обработки. Для строки можно использовать проверку другого типа. В любом случае я всегда буду проверять параметры, даже если, как я написал, **подобная запись вроде как гарантирует безопасность.**