# Как обработать строку в c# перед добавлением в базу?

Tags: c#, sql, ado

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
string q = "UPDATE students SET name = @name where id = @id";
cn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(q, cn);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", WebBrowser1.DocumentText);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 3);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Код не проверял, он чисто для представления, проблема совсем другая.
Как добавить в базу строку с кавычками, двойными кавычками, спец символами и т.д. и (или) как её обработать?

В PHP есть функция `addslashes()`

Спасибо, вопрос исчерпан )

Comment: [Защита от SQL инъекций](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448169/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-sql-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9/448173#448173)

Comment: Хорошо бы в ваш пример добавить `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()`. А то пример бессмысленный.

Comment: Перегрелся я видимо ) не так давно начал "шарпея" мучить. Может какую литературу подскажите?

Comment: Вот ещё [хороший ответ по теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423434/10105).

Comment: @VladimirH: Кое-какая литература есть [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/10105).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете параметры - это аналог prepared statement в PHP.

Ваш код корректно добавит строку с кавычками и прочими спецсимволами

(если не забудете выполнить сам запрос - через `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()`, как подсказывает MaLS)

На всякий случай убедитесь, что строка в базе типа `nvarchar`, а не просто `varchar` - иначе большая часть юникода потеряется.